# Gaussian Process Regression Without Kernel

Tags: stochastic-processes, gaussian-process

I am working on a sequential estimation problem that involves a Bayesian update to a multivariate Gaussian prior from a measurement with Gaussian noise. Specifically, I have a mean vector of length n and covariance matrix of size (n,n) generated from some data, but without an assumed analytical form of the covariance function. The measurements come in one at a time, such that there is a scalar measurement with associated variance at one of the support points of the mean vector.

I've been reading up on Gaussian process regression and everything I've found requires evaluating the kernel function to get the off-diagonal blocks of the joint distribution. Is it possible to update the covariance matrix in a Bayesian sense without assuming an analytical covariance kernel?

Edit: to clarify, the problem I am treating is statistics of density vs. altitude. This is theoretically treated as a Gaussian random field (GRF), since the pdf of density at any value of altitude in the considered range is Gaussian, and there is correlation structure between altitudes. To represent this field, I have a large dataset of density values provided along a given discretization, such as from 1 to 100 km alt. in steps of 1 km. I form a mean vector and covariance matrix from this dataset, which approximate the mean and covariance functions of the GRF.

I would then like to update the mean and covariance based on new data, and was looking at tools from Gaussian process regression to do so. It does indeed seem like assuming a functional form of the covariance kernel is a key part of the regression, but was asking here if there is an approach that circumvents this need.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the connection between the first and second paragraphs. In the first para., it seems that you're just collecting new data over time, and using the Bayesian framework to estimate the mean and covariance of a single Gaussian distribution. But in the second para., you're describing a Gaussian process, which suggests that every finite collection of. your variables is multivariate Gaussian. There's a big difference! Can you [edit] to explain what problem you're trying to solve and how GPs fit into estimating the mean and covariance of the quantities of interest?

Comment: Kernels are *key part* of the Gaussian process, what exactly do you mean by GP without kernels?

Comment: @Sycorax edited to clarify, hope that helps. I'm dealing with finite discretized data associated with a Gaussian process.

Comment: Kernel functions are essential to Gaussian processes. If you want to give up the "kernel" component, you're also giving up "Gaussian process."

Comment: I thought that might be the case. The correct approach would be to select a kernel based on the data and then optimize its parameters over the a priori data, correct?

Comment: That seems like a perfectly valid Question to ask in its own post, or an [edit] to this one. It would help if you could elaborate the details of what you mean by "kernel based on the data" and "optimize its parameters over the a priori data" in the new question.